# APM Server has still not connected to Elasticsearch in docker-compose

Tags: python, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, apm

I have the following docker-compose in order to store logs from fastapi.

```
  apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:7.13.0
    cap_add: ["CHOWN", "DAC_OVERRIDE", "SETGID", "SETUID"]
    cap_drop: ["ALL"]
    networks:
      - es-net
    ports:
    - 8200:8200
    command: >
       apm-server -e
         -E apm-server.rum.enabled=true
         -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601
         -E setup.template.settings.index.number_of_replicas=0
         -E apm-server.kibana.enabled=true
         -E apm-server.kibana.host=kibana:5601
         -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 12
      test: curl --write-out 'HTTP %{http_code}' --fail --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8200/

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - es-net
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.0
    networks:
      - es-net
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local
  
networks:
  es-net:
    driver: bridge
```

The problem is that kibana doesn't recognise the APM service

[image]

The fastapi is configured with the following:

```
from elasticapm.contrib.starlette import make_apm_client, ElasticAPM

apm = make_apm_client({
    'SERVICE_NAME': 'service'
})

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(ElasticAPM, client=apm)
```

Any idea about how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us APM container logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved changing the apm-server to 7.4.0